# nodejs post method is not saving data

Tags: node.js, post, save, http-status-code-500

i have post method which is working fine when i do as shown below

```
var companyDetailsModel = mongoose.model('companyDetails')
router.post('/companyDetails', function(req, res, next) {
    var newCompanyDetails = new companyDetailsModel();

    newCompanyDetails.companyName=req.body.companyName;
    newCompanyDetails.streetAddress=req.body.streetAddress;
    newCompanyDetails.city=req.body.city;
    newCompanyDetails.Street=req.body.Street;
    newCompanyDetails.ZipCode=req.body.ZipCode;
    newCompanyDetails.Phone=req.body.Phone;
    newCompanyDetails.Fax=req.body.Fax;
    newCompanyDetails.webSite=req.body.webSite;
    newCompanyDetails.Logo=req.body.Logo;

    newCompanyDetails.save(function(err) {
        if (err){
            console.log('Error in Saving user: '+err);
        }
        console.log('User Registration succesful');
        res.send("user added sucessfully");
    });

})
```

this route works fine and data is saved in the database but if i try to do it as shown below

```
router.post('/companyDetails', function(req, res, next) {
    var newCompanyDetails = new companyDetailsModel();
    newCompanyDetails= req.body;
    newCompanyDetails.save(function(err) {
        if (err){
            console.log('Error in Saving user: '+err);
        }
        console.log('User Registration succesful');
        res.send("user added sucessfully");
    });

})
```

i will get internal server error like newCompanyDetails.save is not a function please say why is this behavior if a post request contains 100 of  fields should i explicitly should i  assign all the fields please help me understand this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you erase mongo object with this line

```
newCompanyDetails= req.body;
```

Do this instead :

```
 var newCompanyDetails = new companyDetailsModel(req.body);
```

Comment: ossom that worked can u please explain what is happening here so that it worked

Comment: new companyDetailsModel create a new mongo model, when you pass javascript object to it, it set the object with the good field-values. When you do newCompanyDetails=req.body you replace the mongo object to a standard javascript object, in which mongo function like save() aren't defined